# How do you turn on write blocking to USBs on a Mac?

Tags: macos, usb, unix

I'm trying to capture a forensic image of a USB stick using Linux dd on my Macbook.  I'm having trouble turning on write blocking to the USB stick before taking the image.  In Windows you use a registry tweak to prevent writing on the USB stick- how do you do this on Mac (without spending money for a DLP solution)?

Is this still valid to achieve that effect on MacOS, or did an update nullify it:
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/IOUSBMassStorageClass.kext

Answer (score 1):

The command you quote has never been able to give the effect you want. That command disables USB mass storage class devices entirely - i.e. you wouldn't be able to read the device at all (nor would you be able to write to it). It wouldn't be useful when you want to capture a forensic image.

Instead a way to go would be to stop the standard macOS automounter from mounting your USB stick as read/write. Then you could either mount it as read-only, or simply not mount it at all. Then you can take your forensic image.

A simple way to do that is to install [Disk Arbitrator](https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator), which is a freely available utility. Ensure that the icon indicates either green (block mounts entirely) or orange (mounts as read-only) before proceeding to plugging in the USB stick.

If you prefer a command line way of achieving something similar, you could disable auto mounting by this command:

```
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.diskarbitrationd.plist
```

Remember to test that this works with a test USB stick before using the real stick you want to create an image from.

You should be aware that this method is not "fool-proof". I.e. it will stop the system from auto-mounting the drive and contaminating it with Spotlight indices or similar. However, it does protect the USB stick from you doing stupid things. I.e. if you decide to use `dd` to write to the drive instead of reading from it, you will be able to do just that.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Your explanation is great.